# Onmouseover change image transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code snippet to change the src of an `img` tag when I hover over it.

```html
<img src="./Path/to/image.png" alt="" class="exhibit-banner-img" onmouseover="this.src='./Path/to/newimage.png'" onmouseout="this.src='./Path/to/image.png'">
```

It runs as expected, but how do I add a transition time to the image when the event is fired?
Right now, it changes instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.

```css
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-container img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.img-container img:first-child {
  position: relative;
}

.img-container img:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.img-container:hover img:last-child {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<span class="img-container">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg">
</span>
```